# Editing two canvas elements

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have two canvas elements, the first one is empty, and in the second I drawed a big grid. 
In that first one I need to add text and images which are going to be dragged to the grid. The problem is, when I add a text to the empty canvas, the grid disappears!! I don't know how does that happen. I'm using simple code in the script tag:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
ctx2.fillText("Catalog of equipments",10,50);
```

And I'm calling the two canvases in the body:

```
<canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=1000 style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3; left:320px; top:50px"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas" width=1000 height=1000 style="border:2px solid #c3c3c3; top:50px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: how are you drawing the grid?

Comment: It's already drawn in canvas, now I need to put a text in canvas2.

Comment: I understand that, how it has been drawn could be relevant

Comment: I referred to this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117684/how-to-create-dynamic-grid/21119488

Comment: And how have you implemented thay o

Comment: How have you implemented that in your code? A jsfiddle would help

Comment: I was trying to put my code on jsfiddle. Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/uS4er/1/
There is something wrong. It doesn't show the second canvas where there is a grid, although it works perfectly for me (I'm editing with Notepad++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS4er/1/) you have spelt FillText with a capital F rather than fillText. I have corrected in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uS4er/2/).

```
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.font = "30px Arial";
ctx2.fillText ("Catalog of equipments",10,50);
```